# How to prove when $R$ is not a commutative ring, $M\otimes_R N$ is not a module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, noncommutative-algebra

I know how to prove when $R$ is a commutative ring, $M\otimes_R N$ is a module, but how to prove when $R$ is non-commutative ring, we cannot give any module structure on $M\otimes_R N$? I see many answers say that we cannot define $r(m\otimes n)$= $m\otimes rn$ because it will broke the bilinearity. However, it is not the only way to define $$h: R\times (M\otimes_R N)\to (M\otimes_R N),$$ right?  If I want to show $M\otimes_R N$ is not a module, I need to prove any function $h$ cannot satisfy axioms of module. I think it  can be proved by contradiction: assume that $h$ is a function makes $M\otimes_R N$ become a module, then for each $r\in R$, $h_r$ is a homomorphism from $M\otimes_R N$ to $M\otimes_R N$, and correspond a bilinear function from $M\times N$ to $M\otimes_R N$. But I don't know how to do next, can you give me some hints to help me finish the proof or give me another proof show that when $R$ is not a  commutative ring, $M\otimes_R N$ is not a module? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is something you can really prove in any generality, as for example $M \otimes_R N = 0$ is always an $R$-module. By construction, if $M$ is a right-$R$-module and $N$ a left-$R$-module, then $M \otimes_R N$ is just some abelian group. This reduces the problem to imposing any $R$-module structure on some given abelian group, which is sometimes possible and sometimes not. Any remark along the lines of "$M \otimes_R N$ is not an $R$-module" implicitly assumes you are trying to extend the given $R$-module structures of $M$ and $N$ to the tensor product, which indeed fails

Comment: If you want _an example_ where $M\otimes_RN$ is not a right $R$ module, that makes sense.  When one sees the statement "when $R$ is a commutative ring then $M\otimes_RN$ is an $R$ module" one should not then start thinking "OH if $R$ is noncommutative then it must NOT be an $R$ module."  It should be "there might be a noncommutative $R$ somewhere such that..."